# Google Earth Engine Python API, image .and(image2) function

Tags: javascript, python, google-earth-engine

Using the `.and(image2)` in python gives an 'invalid syntax' error because it confuses it with the boolean operator that returns a boolean. Whereas in earth engine JavaScript, ee.Image.and(image2) returns an ee.Image. What is the Python equivalent for this .and operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent statement is `.And(image2)`, as noted [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install):

[image]